# JBoss6 : HTTP 404 while rendering (SEAM)

Tags: seam, seam2

Im using JBOSS Seam 2.2.1 and I am trying to work with application server Jboss6 .In some of the pages, I get HTTP 404 error page while performing actions like search, that would rerender some componets. When I navigate back to the previous page, I am being able to see the search result. In some other pages using rich:modalpanel there is not error, but the result doesn't get rendered. I dont get an exception in both the cases. This issue doesn't arise if application server Jboss5.1 is used. Could someone please help me on this issue.

**This is the stacktrace I got when I replaced richFaces  with the latest version RichFaces 3.3.3.Final:**

> javax.faces.FacesException: javax.faces.FacesException: Cant instantiate class: org.richfaces.component.html.HtmlDataTable.
>       at com.sun.faces.application.ApplicationImpl.createComponent(ApplicationImpl.java:562)
>       at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamApplication.createComponent(SeamApplication.java:92)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.createComponent(ComponentHandler.java:243)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:139)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:109)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.DefineHandler.applyDefinition(DefineHandler.java:64)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:131)
>       at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext$TemplateManager.apply(DefaultFaceletContext.java:337)
>       at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeDefinition(DefaultFaceletContext.java:307)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.InsertHandler.apply(InsertHandler.java:68)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:109)
>       at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
>       at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
>       at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
>       at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
>       at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
>       at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:140)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.IncludeHandler.apply(IncludeHandler.java:65)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.applyNextHandler(ComponentHandler.java:314)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.ComponentHandler.apply(ComponentHandler.java:169)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.jsf.core.ViewHandler.apply(ViewHandler.java:109)
>       at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.CompositeFaceletHandler.apply(CompositeFaceletHandler.java:47)
>       at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
>       at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:248)
>       at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:294)
>       at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.include(DefaultFacelet.java:273)
>       at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFaceletContext.includeFacelet(DefaultFaceletContext.java:140)
>       at com.sun.facelets.tag.ui.CompositionHandler.apply(CompositionHandler.java:113)
>       at com.sun.facelets.compiler.NamespaceHandler.apply(NamespaceHandler.java:49)
>       at com.sun.facelets.compiler.EncodingHandler.apply(EncodingHandler.java:25)
>       at com.sun.facelets.impl.DefaultFacelet.apply(DefaultFacelet.java:95)
>       at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.buildView(FaceletViewHandler.java:524)
>       at com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler.renderView(FaceletViewHandler.java:567

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just change the rich faces & Other component libraries corresponding to seam new version

Comment: I have changed the library with those available with JBosssSeam 2.2.1.Final version. It didn't help. The same application when deployed using JBoss 5.1 works fine. But due to performance issues, I would like to have it deployed in JBoss6. Is their any other fix. Thank you Jennifer for your suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

chech this : [Conversational components and JSF component bindings](http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.2.1.Final/reference/en-US/html/conversations.html#d0e6518)

Also take a look at ***components.xml***

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <components xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/components"
xmlns:core="http://jboss.com/products/seam/core"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="
http://jboss.com/products/seam/core
http://jboss.com/products/seam/core-2.2.xsd
 http://jboss.com/products/seam/components
http://jboss.com/products/seam/components-2.2.xsd">
<core:init jndi-pattern="@jndiPattern@"/>
 </components>
```

Comment: I had problem with seam-mail when deployed in JBoss6. That issue got solved when I replaced library with the latest version JBossSeam 2.2.1.Final.

Comment: I have tried with the latest version of RichFaces : RichFaces 3.3.3.Final, but now even the rich faces components such as datatable are not been instatiated. I get an exception.

Comment: I have fixed the issue. All the methods had a return type, which was the problem. When a return is given for a method, in seam applications it would look for a navigation in the pages. When the return was String the issue of 404 arised. Otherwise the result doesn't get rendered.

Comment: We don't have to change the richfaces lib to RichFaces 3.3.3.Final